# deserialize a .NET object on another platform

Tags: .net, matlab, serialization

I have a file containing data created by the BinaryFormatter.Serialize method of the .NET framework.  I would like to import this data (specifically, the values of certain properties of the described object) into MATLAB in an automated way.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I know nothing about .NET but assume that installing the whole .NET framework and using their deserializer is possible but complicated, and since I can otherwise do everything entirely within MATLAB I'm hoping there is a simpler way.

Comment: If the intent was to create a portable format, the .NET code should have used a different serializer, maybe XML.

Comment: True. But I can't control that. I actually made some progress on this-- I found that MATLAB can load the relevant .NET assemblies easily, and I can call the deserializer.  The remaining problem is that I cannot get the deserializer to "see" the private assembly which defines the output format of the deserialize command.  I can load that private assembly, and import its functions, but the deserialize command still says "unable to find assembly."  Placing the private DLL in the matlab win32 directory, as suggested on the mathworks site, did not solve the problem.

Comment: Actually I figured it out, somewhat to my surprise.  Turns out I needed to run 64-bit matlab, and putting the private DLL in the matlab bin/win64 directory worked!  In case it helps others, the relevant MATLAB commands were as follows:    bf=System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter;  inputstream=System.IO.FileStream('pathtoyourfile',System.IO.FileMode.Open,System.IO.FileAccess.Read,System.IO.FileShare.Read);  ret_obj=System.Object;  ds=NET.addAssembly('path_to_private_assembly_defining_datatype');  import ds.*  ret_obj=bf.Deserialize(inputstream);

Comment: That sounds like an answer, although I would change the title of your question to "in MATLAB", because "just load the .NET DLL" won't work for all platforms.